# How to solve a linear programing in matlab in canonical representation?

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

Is it possible to enter matlab a string like that:

```
MAX  140 x1 + 160 x2 +x3

SUBJECT TO

2 x1 + 4 x2 <= 28

5x1 + 5.333x2 -500X3 = 0

x1 <= 8

x2 <= 6

END
```

The toolbox I have installed:

> > v = ver;
> >     setdiff({v.Name}, 'MATLAB')'

ans =

```
'Aerospace Blockset'
'Aerospace Toolbox'
'Bioinformatics Toolbox'
'Communications System Toolbox'
'Computer Vision System Toolbox'
'Control System Toolbox'
'Curve Fitting Toolbox'
'DSP System Toolbox'
'Database Toolbox'
'Datafeed Toolbox'
'Econometrics Toolbox'
'Embedded Coder'
'Filter Design HDL Coder'
'Financial Derivatives Toolbox'
'Financial Toolbox'
'Fixed-Income Toolbox'
'Fixed-Point Toolbox'
'Fuzzy Logic Toolbox'
'Global Optimization Toolbox'
'IEC Certification Kit'
'Image Acquisition Toolbox'
'Image Processing Toolbox'
'Instrument Control Toolbox'
'MATLAB Builder JA'
'MATLAB Coder'
'MATLAB Compiler'
'MATLAB Distributed Computing Server'
'MATLAB Report Generator'
'Mapping Toolbox'
'Model Predictive Control Toolbox'
'Neural Network Toolbox'
'Optimization Toolbox'
'Parallel Computing Toolbox'
'Partial Differential Equation Toolbox'
'Phased Array System Toolbox'
'RF Toolbox'
'Robust Control Toolbox'
'Signal Processing Toolbox'
'SimBiology'
'SimDriveline'
'SimElectronics'
'SimEvents'
'SimHydraulics'
'SimMechanics'
'SimPowerSystems'
'SimRF'
'Simscape'
'Simulink'
'Simulink 3D Animation'
'Simulink Coder'
'Simulink Control Design'
'Simulink Design Optimization'
'Simulink Fixed Point'
'Simulink Report Generator'
'Simulink Verification and Validation'
'Stateflow'
'Statistics Toolbox'
'Symbolic Math Toolbox'
'System Identification Toolbox'
'SystemTest'
'Wavelet Toolbox'
```

Comment: Yes, but you'd need to write some code to parse it.

Comment: Do you have Linear Programming toolbox ?

Comment: @miy here is the list of toolbox I have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check out [`linprog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html):

```
f = [140, 160, 1]'; %'
A = [2 4 0];
b = 28;
Aeq = [5 5.3333 -500]
beq = 0
lb = -inf*ones(3,1);
ub = [8, 6, inf]';

x = linprog( f, A, b, Aeq, beq, lb, ub );
```

Comment: thanks, is it possible to write it as pseudo text? I hav hundreds of variables

Comment: you can use `regexp` or similar functinos to parse your inputs. `linprog` is quite efficient and can handle lots of variables. If you are looking for heavier packages, look at [`lp_solve`](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/).

Answer (score 3):

[YALMIP](http://users.isy.liu.se/johanl/yalmip/pmwiki.php?n=Main.HomePage) will get you closer to what you want. You might also want to look into [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/).

Comment: Yalmip only provides a wrapper/interface to many solvers. From my experience this wrapping comes with quite an "overhead" in terms of extra variables and memory.  So, if you are going to use a specific solver you better tune your code to it and eliminate the "middle man"

Comment: @Shai I agree, but OP is asking for a modeling language in MATLAB that is easy to input and also asked about solving LPs, which likely won't be too difficult to solve. It's not clear if they're trying to solve MIPs.